# MongoDB object meeting two conditions in array of objects

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I have a collection that contains objects with array of objects inside:

```
{
    _id: 12345,
    data: [
        {
            state: 1,
            type: 3,
            info: "abc"
        },{
            state: 2,
            type: 3,
            info: "cde"
        },{
            state: 2,
            type: 3,
            info: "efg"
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to select objects from collection that *{data.state: 2, data.type: 3}*, but in case of running this query, I will get objects that contain objects with **state: 2** and **type: 3**, but not **an object** containing **state: 2** and **type: 3**.

How can I match two criteria within one object in array of objects? How can I select objects that only contain objects with both **state: 2** and **type: 3**?

P.S. I know of  $elemMatch, but that will return only { state: 2, type: 3, info: "cde" } from the sample object above, while I need all of the **data**.

P.P.S. Here are some sample results:

Object that is checked:

```
 data: [
    {
        state: 1,
        type: 3
    },{
        state: 2,
        type: 3
    },{
        state: 2,
        type: 3
    }
]
```

Is output: Yes (there are 2 objects containing both state 2 AND type 3)

```
data: [
    {
        state: 1,
        type: 3
    },{
        state: 2,
        type: 4
    },{
        state: 2,
        type: 0
    }
]
```

Is output: No (there is not a single object containing state 2 AND type 3)

```
data: [
    {
        state: 5,
        type: 3
    },{
        state: 1,
        type: 3
    },{
        state: 1,
        type: 4
    },{
        state: 2,
        type: 3
    }
]
```

Is output: Yes (there is one object containing state 2 AND type 3)

Comment: can you give an example of what the query should return?

Comment: @benjaminjosephw I've updated the question. You can see what object Mongo is looking at and whenever it should be included in results or not.

Answer (score 0):

**$elemMatch** returns the first matching element in the array. You can use Aggregation Framework to get what you want.

```
db.collection.aggregate(
  {$unwind : "$data"},
  {$match : {"data.state" : 2, "data.type" : 3}}
)
```